# How to do cascading delete in Objectify?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify, nosql

I've been searching for that past couple days and couldn't find an answer that satisfies me.

Yes, I did look into this post [how-do-you-implement-cascading-delete-in-objectify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455098/how-do-you-implement-cascading-delete-in-objectify) and many other posts from Google Developer forums.

Everybody says that "It is different from Relational Database", but nobody posted an implementation for that.

These are my models,

**University**

```
public class University{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    List<Ref<College>> colleges = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**College**

```
public class College{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;
}
```

I simplified my models to make it look cleaner. I want to delete the University and Colleges at the same time.

In this example there is a hierarchy of two levels, but in my project I have hierarchy of three levels. Finding childs and grandchilds of an entity and deleting them doesn't seem very efficient to me.

Answer (score 1):

As everybody say *It is different from Relational Database*.

You don't have *relations*, so you cannot delete "*all related objects*", by definition. You have to delete each entity one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If your data really is one unreferenced hierarchy, consider modeling it with embedded objects, so there's only one underlying document. Then an update or delete will be on one datastore entity.

If it isn't, then when you do want to delete, there must be logic about what can and can't be deleted, which you need to program yourself